# Foreach is not working my admin dashboard "Undefined variable: users" laravel

Tags: laravel

So i have a table that shows all users in the admin views and in there it works well I can see all the users modify them and such so i thought i could just use the same table and add it on my dashboard of the admin as a way to quick access the data but i get this error

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
> Undefined variable: users (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hr_system\resources\views\admin.blade.php)

And this is what it suggests as a solution from laravel

> $users is undefined
> Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $users }} with {{ $users ?? '' }}

This is the code im using on the admin dashboard its the same as the one in the users

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->first_name}} {{$user->last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->phone}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->gender}}</td>
        @if($user->role_id ==1)
            <td>User</td>
        @else
            <td>Manager</td>
        @endif
        <td>Position</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

And this is the UsersController

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::all();

    return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

It has more functions if needed i can share them all as well
Well that is my question I don't understand why its not recognizing the users when it works on another file in the same admin folder

Comment: The error is in `resources\views\admin.blade.php`, the controller method you showed points to a different template/view. You probably have another method somewhere that calls the view without `$users`

Comment: Is there a way i can return 2 views then?

Comment: Return two views? From one method? How would that work? You can include views in other views - or use [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers) to make `$users` available in multiple views

Comment: Okay i fixed it apparently i should have used this return view('admin', compact('users')); in the admin controller after that it works thank you for you help btw i was able to find this from the views composers link